# Automated execution of a Colab notebook on a recurring schedule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scheduled-tasks, google-colaboratory

Is there a reliable way of executing a Google Colab notebook at a specific schedule ? This recurring schedule should not require me to open my laptop to execute or trigger it in any way.

I also have a free trial of GCP as well in case that is helpful.

Thank you for taking the time to read this !

Answer (score 6):

This is a feature that the team at Google Colab is considering adding, but you can already schedule notebooks to run on GCP: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/how-to-schedule-a-recurring-python-script-on-gcp

Comment: Any updates about if this ended up being rolled into colaboratory as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium for this one. It may be overkill but you can use it for free.

```py
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

COLAB_URL = 'https://colab.research.google.com/drive/CHANGE'
DOWNLOAD_FOLDER = 'CHANGEME/Downloads/' 
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = 'copy.txt'

def run_colab(COLAB_URL=COLAB_URL, DOWNLOAD_FOLDER=DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, OUTPUT_FILE_NAME=OUTPUT_FILE_NAME):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"--download.default_directory={DOWNLOAD_FOLDER}")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=CHANGEME/.config/google-chrome/Default") # Added line

    wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    wd.get(COLAB_URL)
    print(wd.title)
    print("Page loaded")

    wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10)
    runtime_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'runtime-menu-button')))
    runtime_button.click()
    action_chains = ActionChains(wd)
    action_chains.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(Keys.F9).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    print("Running colab...")
    print("Waiting for the task to complete...")

    while not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, OUTPUT_FILE_NAME)):
        time.sleep(1)

    print("Task completed")

    time.sleep(5)

    print("Closing Driver...")

    wd.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_colab()
```

Also Jupyter notebook code

```py
from google.colab import files
import time
with open("copy.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("Hello")

files.download("copy.txt")
```

After that you can create cronjob for python script.

```py
0 8 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path_to_your_script/run_colab.py
```

This example would run the script every day at 8:00 AM. Adjust the timing as needed.